# Why an ancient vampire sleeping for centuries under some castle in Europe would come to Brazil?

Tags: fiction, plot, fantasy, comedy, monsters

A vampire has been sleeping under a castle in Austria for centuries. But now the castle became a tourist attraction. It's really annoying. And the taste of the blood of the people on the region didn't change. Why would he come to Brazil?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.  Questions asking *what* to write, such as plot ideas, are off-topic here (and tend to be pretty subjective).  We can help you with questions about how to convey an idea or structure a plot or reveal worldbuilding, but the actual content is still up to you.  Please check out our short [tour].  Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

He wouldn´t...but if you really must:

- I guess you could have him hanker for exotic blood cocktails and dancing the samba.
- Some of the tourists visiting the caste were brasileros and tasted so good.
- He gets married and takes a blood-moon trip to Rio.
- The last occupants of the castle, his "family", were Nazi Austrian officers who fled to the Amazon jungle to escape justice...
- He is tired of Austrian prudeness and wants to wear a man´s thongs, a string bikini with pouch and flaunt that he is a stiff. :)

This took me all of 2 minutes....there could be so many reasons, but the premise seems dumb and is reminiscent of Bella´s Twightlight honeymoon.

Comment: #1 is best. He hears a song on the radio and can't get that crazy rhythm out of his system. He takes dancing lessons and heads to Rio.